# try is returning Either instead of IO (Either ex a)

Tags: haskell, exception

I'm trying to handle exceptions from my request parser:

```
   go bs =                                                                 
       case try $ parseRequest reader bs secure of                             
         Left  ex             -> exceptionHandler writer ex                 
         Right (request, bs') -> do                                         
            sendResponse writer =<< app request                             
            go bs'
```

But I have an issue when using `try`:

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO (Either e0 (Request, ByteString))'
            with actual type `Either t0 t1'
In the pattern: Left ex
In a case alternative: Left ex -> exceptionHandler writer ex
In the expression:
  case try $ parseRequest reader bs secure of {
    Left ex -> exceptionHandler writer ex
    Right (request, bs')
      -> do { sendResponse writer =<< app request;
              go bs' } }
```

`IO (Either e0 (Request, ByteString))` is exactly what I except to get from `try` because its type is `try :: Exception e => IO a -> IO (Either e a)`, but instead I get `Either e a`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`try` does produce an `IO (Either e a)`. You're getting the error message because you're matching the value produced by `try` against the pattern `Left ex`, which has the type `Either a b`, not `IO a`.

To fix your code, you'd need to get the `Either` out of the `IO` (using `>>=` or `<-` inside `do`) and then pattern match against that.

Answer (score 5):

In GHC 7.6 and later, you can use

```
try (parseRequest reader bs secure) >>= \case
    Left ex -> ...
    Right (request, bs') -> ...
```

If you enable `{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}`