# try won't handle any exceptions

Tags: haskell, exception

This is based on the suggestion from my earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741139/try-is-returning-either-instead-of-io-either-ex-a):

```
    go bs = do
       r <- try $ parseRequest reader bs secure
       case r of
         Left ex -> do
            putStrLn "got exception"
            exceptionHandler writer ex
            go empty
         Right (request, bs') -> do
            sendResponse writer =<< app request
            go bs'
```

When there is no exception, the Right part runs no problem. However when an exception is thrown, the exception bubbles all the way to the top and Left isn't run. It doesn't seem to mater what kind of exception it is.

Here are the exceptions that is it supposed to catch (though it also won't catch `error`):

```
data ParseError                                                                 
    = Unexpected                                                                
    | MalformedRequestLine ByteString                                           
    | MalformedHeader      ByteString                                           
    | MissingHeader        ByteString Headers                                   
    | UnknownSIPVersion    ByteString                                           
      deriving (Typeable, Show, Eq)    

instance Exception ParseError
```

Here is the type of exceptionHandler:

```
exceptionHandler :: (ByteString -> IO ())                                         
             -> ParseError                                                    
             -> IO ()
```

Also this is version 7.4.1 of ghc.

Any ideas why?

Comment: It's almost certainly because of the type of `exceptionHandler`, which is conveniently nowhere to be found in this snippet. Unless, of course, it's an exception caused by pure code inside of the parser that doesn't get thrown until something is forced. Either way, this question is missing a great deal of important information.

Comment: Which `try` are you using?  What exception is being missed?  What exception type are you handling?  Your question is far too incomplete.

Comment: Why would the type of exceptionHandler matter? It can't be used for pattern matching, can it?

Comment: @Joehillen It matters because the return value of `try` (from `Control.Exception`, Thomas made the excellent point it could be a different `try`) depends on what exceptions it's catching. Since this isn't a compile error, the only thing that could determine the type of the `Left` case is the call to `exceptionHandler`.

Comment: @hammar yes, that's there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you're using a `throw` which doesn't get evaluated within the scope of the `try`. In that case, you will get the exception after the `try` instead, when you try to use the result. If you can, use `throwIO` instead to ensure that the exception gets thrown at the correct time.

Notice the difference:

```
> :set -XDeriveDataTypeable
> :m + Control.Exception Data.Typeable
> data Boom = Boom deriving (Show, Typeable)
> instance Exception Boom
> try $ return (throw Boom) :: IO (Either Boom Int)
Right *** Exception: Boom
> try $ throwIO Boom :: IO (Either Boom Int)
Left Boom
```

Comment: BINGO! I have been fighting with this issue for 3 days. Thank you so much!

Comment: alternative using [evaluate](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.6.0.1/Control-Exception.html#v:evaluate) without changing your code
```try (evaluate ...```

Answer (score 1):

Your question pains me because if you use the correct `try` it should work, but you have failed to provide a minimum example.  Instead, I will provide a functional example and leave it to you to determine what is different in your code.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
```

I only needed `ScopedTypeVariables` because I didn't use an explicitly typed function.

```
import Control.Exception as X
import Data.ByteString as B
import Data.Typeable
import Data.Data
```

Notice I am using the `Control.Exception` module, and the `try` function from there.  I suspect your `try` comes from elsewhere.

```
data ParseError
    = Unexpected
    | MalformedRequestLine ByteString
    | MalformedHeader      ByteString
    | MissingHeader        ByteString ()
    | UnknownSIPVersion    ByteString
      deriving (Typeable, Show, Eq)

instance Exception ParseError

parseRequest :: IO Int
parseRequest = throw Unexpected
```

For testing, my `parseResult` just throws something.

```
exceptionHandler :: (ByteString -> IO ())
                 -> ParseError
                 -> IO ()
exceptionHandler f p = print p

main = do
  r <- X.try parseRequest
  case r of
    Right i -> print i
    Left (e :: ParseError) -> print ("Caught",e)
```

And the main routine is pretty boring - just a summary of the important parts of your routine.  It runs fine:

```
$ ghc so.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( so.hs, so.o )
Linking so ...
$ ./so
("Caught",Unexpected)
```

If you modify the exception to a different type you'll see the exception is not caught:

```
parseRequest :: IO Int
parseRequest = error "This is a different type, and won't be caught by 'ParseError' handlers."
```

With a result of:

```
$ ./so
so: This is a different type, thus not caught by 'ParseError' handlers.
```

If you wish to catch ALL exceptions then you need a type that suffices for that task.

Comment: "Your question pains me because if you use the correct try it should work, but you have failed to provide a minimum example." Your snark is unnecessary and unhelpful. If it's so painful for you, why bother answering?

Comment: Well, I do like to help but one of the most frustrating things on SO (to me) is incomplete or under-specified questions.

Comment: @Joehillen: To be fair, if you had included the code where the exception was thrown, we would have been able to spot the problem easily without guessing. Small and _complete_ examples make things easier for everyone.